# JQuery Datepicker: how to deny it using my css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

I have a Javascript JQuery datepicker attached to 2 text fields.

In Chrome, this works perfectly. In IE9, whenever I click on the text fields, the calendar field opens BUT when I want to select a date, the control flickers because the hover effect does inherit from some CSS.

I want to know if there's a way for me to deny the control to be using my css (such as  or ) and just revert to the base browser visual style.

This way, I can start building it up from scratch and test where the flickering occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
pointer-events:  auto | none
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you explain me what this does?

Comment: I'm sorry, it didn't. I have solved this problem myself by redesigning my css-code.